# How can I identify the source of a volume inside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, containers

Tl;Dr: is there a way to check if a volume `/foo` built into a docker image has been overwritten at runtime by remounting using `-v host/foo:/foo`?

I have designed an image that runs a few scripts on container initialization using `s6-overlay` to dynamically generate a user, transfer permissions, and launch a few services under that uid:gid.

One of the things I need to do is `pip install -e /foo` a python module mounted at `/foo`. This also installs a default version of `/foo` contained in the docker image if the user doesn't specify a volume. The reason I am doing this install at runtime is because this container is designed to contain the entire environment for development and experimentation of `foo`, so if a user mounts a system version of `foo`, e.g. `-v /home/user/foo:/foo`, the user can develop by updating `host:/home/user/foo` or in `container:/foo` and all changes will persist and the image won't need to be rebuilt to get new changes. It needs to be an editable install so that new changes don't require reinstallation.

I have this working now.

I would like to speed up container initialization by moving this `pip install` into the image build, and then only install the module at runtime if the user has mounted a new `/foo` at runtime using `-v /home/user/foo:/foo`.

Of course, there are other ways to do this. For example, I could build `foo` into the image copying it to `/bar` at build time and install `foo` using `pip install /bar`... Then at runtime just check if `/foo` exists and if it doesn't then create a symlink `/foo->/bar`. If it does exist then `pip uninstall foo` and `pip install -e /foo`.. but this isn't the cleanest solution. I could also just `mv /bar /foo` at runtime if `/foo` doesn't exist.. but I'm not sure how pip will handle the change in module path.

Comment: It sounds like you could solve this just by checking that a particular file or directory under `/foo` exists, and if not, run the install, otherwise assume it's an existing environment.

Comment: that's a good idea @larsks ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this, that I can think of, is to map the docker socket into the container, so you can do `docker inspect` from inside the container and see the mounted volumes. Like this

```
docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker
```

and then inside the container

```
docker inspect $(hostname)
```

I've used the 'docker' image, since that has docker installed. You can, of course, use another image. You just have to install docker in it.

Comment: Very cool. I probably won't use this since it requires the user to mount something else new, but i did not know how to do access the host `docker` before, so today I learned something